# Electric and magnetic field strength of a magnetic monopole. (In absence of electric charges.)

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, magnetic-monopoles

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole#Maxwell%27s_equations), in the presence of magnetic monopoles Maxwell's equations will look like:

[image]

Whilst the potentials will look like:

[image]

So my question is, how would the electric and magnetic field strength equations look like for a magnetic monopole? My guess is only the constants like $\mu_0$ and $\varepsilon_0$ would change, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changes. You just set $\rho_e$ and $\mathbf{j}_e$ (the electric charges and currents) to zero. The resulting expressions will be Maxwell's equations and the expressions for the potentials in terms of magnetic charge and current densities.

Do notice the formulae you're quoting is given in [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units), which set $\epsilon_0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$ and $\mu_0 = \frac{4\pi}{c^2}$. This has to do with your choice of units, not with magnetic monopoles.

Comment: So basically for a magnetic monopole, $\mathbf{E}$ becomes $\mathbf{B}$, and $\mathbf{B}$ becomes $\mathbf{E}$. Where $q$ becomes $q_m$ and $I$ becomes $I_m$. So the formulas will be.
$\mathbf{B}= \frac{q_m}{4 \pi \epsilon _0 r^2}$
$\mathbf{E}= \frac{I_m \mu _0}{2\pi r}$

Comment: @LeonaVeona Not quite. I think you are getting the factors of $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ wrong in those expressions. I meant the $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ factors won't change when you plug in zero for the electric charges and currents in Maxwell's equations. The expressions will be slightly different, and hence so will the solutions

Comment: I meant $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ are constants that do not depend on whether you are considering electric or magnetic monopoles, but they do appear in different places in the expressions

Comment: I just have trouble finding the right expressions.